# c# error in kernelbase.dll on .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm getting the following error for my application on some machines. I'm wandering what the best methods are for debugging this issue - nothing is being logged so it looks like the fault is happening outside my codebase (no doubt caused by something I've done!)

`Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          25/01/2012 2:23:29 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:

User:          N/A
Computer:

Description:
Faulting application name:, version: 2.0.0.64, time stamp: 0x4f1f54ed
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e2111c0
Exception code: 0xe0434f4d
Fault offset: 0x0000d36f
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13`

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816

Comment: If these machines reliably (not 5% of the time) generate this error, have you tried attaching a remote debugger on these machines? (if at all possible) This should give you atleast an idea as to where the problem might be. Also some more details wouldn't hurt, what does this app do, are you using P/Invokes, COM or are you perhaps hosted in another application, release or debug builds etc etc.

Comment: This is what happens when an app crashes because of an uncaught managed exception.  The most common reason for a managed app to crash of course.  Improve your error handling by writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Almost always good enough to pin-point the problem.

Comment: Thanks Hans - the first two lines of code are the following:                 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
                Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
I can't think of why it's not catching it.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 0xe0434f4d is for CLR exceptions.

To debug, you may learn about crash dumps and WinDbg. Below is an example for ASP.NET, but if you know how to capture a crash dump for other kinds of .NET applications, the dump analysis workflow is the same,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/08/net-debugging-demos-lab-2-crash.aspx